# Why can't I get my progress bar activity indicator to display longer in my Kotlin Android app

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom activity which contains a progress bar activity indicator which is visible while a network access is taking place and then made invisible when it has finished the network access. The activity indicator then becomes visible again at the start of another network access and becomes invisible at the end of it. The progress bar activity indicator appears to display twice as expected but there is still a relatively long time between these two occurrences when the user is kept waiting and no activity indicator is being displayed. Are these the best locations from a UX point of view to have the progress bar activity indicator code while some task is being executed?

Here is my custom activity class with the progress bar activity indicator code:

```
package com.riverstonetech.gositeuk

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Color
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.Model.Site
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.Utilities.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_county.*

class CountyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Access Cloud Firestore instance
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    private var sites: ArrayList<Site> = ArrayList()
    private var siteDistances: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var adapter: SiteAdapter? = null
    private var selectedCounty: String? = null
    val REQUEST_CODE = 1000

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_county)

        val window: Window = this.getWindow();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.statusBarColor = Color.argb(255, 16, 128, 116)
        }

        selectedCounty = intent.getStringExtra("SUB_COUNTRY")!!

        // Custom action bar code to return to list of counties
        configureCustomActionBar()

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            Log.d("Debug", "Permission not granted")

            // Permission is not granted
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Alert user to switch Location on in Settings
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                // Set the alert dialog title
                builder.setTitle("Permission needed")

                // Display a message on alert dialog
                builder.setMessage("Please grant permission for \"GoSiteUK\" to use your location")

                // Set a positive button and its click listener on alert dialog
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->

                    startActivity(Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).apply {
                        data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                    })
                }

                // Display a negative button on alert dialog
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
                    val intent = Intent(this, CountriesActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)

                }

                // Finally, make the alert dialog using builder
                val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

                // Display the alert dialog on app interface
                dialog.show()


            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    REQUEST_CODE
                )

                finish()

            }
        } else {

            // Permission has already been granted
            val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == false) {

                // Alert user to switch Location on in Settings
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                // Set the alert dialog title
                builder.setTitle("Turn on \"Location\"")

                // Display a message on alert dialog
                builder.setMessage("\"Location\" is currently turned off. Turn on \"Location\" to enable navigation function in \"GoSiteUK\"")

                // Set a positive button and its click listener on alert dialog
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->

                    val intent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

                // Display a negative button on alert dialog
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
                    val intent = Intent(this, CountriesActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)

                }

                // Finally, make the alert dialog using builder
                val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

                // Display the alert dialog on app interface
                dialog.show()

            } else {

                sites.clear()

                var progressBar: ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.countySitesProgressBar)

                progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE

                db.collection("UKSites")
                    .document("England")
                    .collection("Counties")
                    .document(selectedCounty!!)
                    .collection(selectedCounty!!)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

                        for (document in documents) {

                            val site = Site(document.data["Name"].toString())

                            site.address.line1 = document.data["Address Line 1"].toString()
                            site.address.line2 = document.data["Address Line 2"].toString()
                            site.address.line3 = document.data["Address Line 3"].toString()
                            site.address.line4 = document.data["Address Line 4"].toString()
                            site.address.postcode = document.data["Postcode"].toString()
                            site.address.phoneNumber = document.data["Telephone"].toString()
                            site.address.siteURL = document.data["Site URL"].toString()
                            site.description = document.data["Description"].toString()
                            site.price = document.data["Price"] as Double
                            site.distance = 0
                            site.locationCoordinate.Longitude = document.data["Longitude"] as Double
                            site.locationCoordinate.Latitude = document.data["Latitude"] as Double

                            sites.add(site)

                        }

                        progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.GONE

                        BuildLocationRequest()

                        BuildLocationCallback()

                        // Create FusedProviderClient
                        fusedLocationProviderClient =
                            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

                        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                            locationRequest,
                            locationCallback,
                            Looper.myLooper()
                        )

                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                        Log.e("Error", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    fun configureCustomActionBar() {

        val actionBar: ActionBar? = this.supportActionBar
        actionBar?.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
        actionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
        actionBar?.setCustomView(R.layout.sub_country_action_bar)

        val countyLabel: TextView = findViewById(R.id.subCountryTextView)
        countyLabel.text = selectedCounty

        val view: View? = actionBar?.customView
        actionBar?.setCustomView(view)

    }

    fun BuildLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 5000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 3000
        locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 10f

    }

    fun BuildLocationCallback() {
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {

            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {

                var progressBar: ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.countySitesProgressBar)

                val currentCoordinate = p0!!.locations.get(p0.locations.size - 1)

                // Build URL for web request
                var distanceAPIURL: String = BASE_URL + "&origins="
                var siteLatitude: Double
                var siteLongitude: Double

                // add current location parameter to API URL
                progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE
                distanceAPIURL += "${currentCoordinate.latitude},${currentCoordinate.longitude}"

                // add site destinations to API URL
                distanceAPIURL += "&destinations="

                // Build API request from site locations
                for (site in sites) {

                    siteLatitude = site.locationCoordinate.Latitude!!
                    siteLongitude = site.locationCoordinate.Longitude!!

                    if (site == sites.first()) {

                        distanceAPIURL += "${siteLatitude}%2C${siteLongitude}"

                    } else {

                        distanceAPIURL += "%7C${siteLatitude}%2C${siteLongitude}"

                    }

                }

                // Add API KEY
                distanceAPIURL += GOOGLE_API_KEY

                // Make web requests to Google
                val distanceRequest = object :
                    StringRequest(Method.POST, distanceAPIURL, Response.Listener { response ->


                        // Parse out distances from returned data
                        siteDistances = parseOutDistanceValues(response)

                        // Update distance information for each site
                        for (siteIndex in 0 until sites.size) {

                            sites[siteIndex].distance = siteDistances[siteIndex]

                        }

                        // Sort sites in ascending order of distance
                        sites = sortByDistance(sites)

                        // Recycler View code here
                        recyclerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.countySitesRecyclerView) as RecyclerView

                        adapter = SiteAdapter(this@CountyActivity, sites)

                        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)

                        recyclerView!!.layoutManager = layoutManager

                        recyclerView!!.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()

                        // Add a neat dividing line between items in the list
                        recyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(
                            DividerItemDecoration(
                                this@CountyActivity,
                                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
                            )
                        )

                        recyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(
                            ItemOffsetDecoration(
                                applicationContext,
                                0,
                                0
                            )
                        )

                        // set the adapter
                        recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter

                        progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.GONE


                    }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->

                        Log.d(
                            "ERROR",
                            "Could not calculate distances to sites: ${error.localizedMessage}"
                        )

                    }) {

                }

                Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext).add(distanceRequest)

            }
        }
    }

    fun previousSubCountryListButtonClicked(view: View) {

        val intent: Intent = Intent(this, CountriesActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a few modifications.

1. Declare the progressbar as member of your activity and initilize it (var progressBar: ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.countySitesProgressBar)) from `onCreate`
2. In your layout always show it by default. The only place where you need to hide it is when you send/receive response from your webservice (from what I saw you get a location and then do something with it and pass it to a webservice.
3. (optional) I would recommend you to use dagger or to use design patterns (like mvp/mvvm) to reuse and incapsulate your code more efficiently. If you will need to include more functionality in your activity it will be hard later on to debug it.

**Edit**

If you want to include also a textview as part of your loading screen you can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_20"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"> <--------

            <ProgressBar
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_progressbar_indeterminate"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:text="Fetching Location / Fetching Data..."/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content1">

            <TextView
                tools:text="Can be recyclerview with some data"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The main change is that the progress bar with a text are in a separate layout instead of being part of your content. Instead of changing the visibility of the progress bar you need to change the visibility of the loading layout.

Comment: I've tried doing 1. above but it makes no difference. There is no setting in the layout to show it by default in 2. I don't think 3. is going to make it work as I would like it to.

Comment: Usually when you want to get user's location it will take more time to get it than sending a rest request to a webservice. In the newer ux designs that I saw the progressbar (indeterminate) needs to be below the the toolbar. You can also add a message to the user if the operation takes more than a few seconds (like getting his location )

Comment: Thanks but the progress bar is already below the toolbar or (do you mean the action bar?). I could add a message to the user, yes, but I can't figure out where to put it in my code because I think I have the progress bar switch on/switch off already covering the parts of the code that are taking time to execute.

Comment: it still doesn't help with my original problem.